# Multiple Layouts in Refinery CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

Does anyone know how to make multiple layouts in refinery?  It doesn't have to be in the user admin I just need to be able to programmatically tell some refinery pages to use one layout and others to use a different one.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that you also posted this to the Refinery CMS Google Group http://groups.google.com/group/refinery-cms/browse_thread/thread/879cea21bd2c2063

So, I'll answer there.

Comment: Short answer, there are several ways and a [guide](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/blob/master/doc/guides/3%20-%20Advanced%20Techniques%20and%20Tips/3%20-%20Using%20Custom%20View%20or%20Layout%20Templates.textile) showing each of them.

Comment: Guide link outdated, the repository moved. [Enabling Custom Layout Templates](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/blob/master/doc/guides/3%20-%20Advanced%20Techniques%20and%20Tips/1%20-%20Using%20Custom%20View%20or%20Layout%20Templates.textile#enabling-custom-layout-templates).